# Probability of a gain associated with an ordered draw of 3 persons among 30

Tags: probability, permutations

the question is the following:

A company has 30 employees which participate in a weekly draw. In the draw 3 people are selected (without replacement). The 1st to win wins 100$$,  the 2nd 50$ and the third 25$.

Suppose a wife and a husband work at the company, what is the probability that at least one of them wins money?

The way we have been doing these questions is generally by finding the sample space and then looking for the sample points in the specific events (in this case we only have one event : at least one of them wins a prize)

I think I can to find the sample space, which is a permutation (30P3) but I find myself unable to go further.

Perhaps I do not understand the way to approach these questions and any help or hint is absolutely welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I'm having some trouble with this probability question." isn't a title.  I  change it inyo something that is related to the question.

Comment: Thank you it is my first time posting, so definitely appreciate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Think about the complement probability: what is the probability that no one of them wins money? In this case the $3$ selected persons belong to a group of $30-2$ people.

Comment: I definitely see how that approach is much simpler, however even that, I am not sure how to find! Perhaps 28/30 for the first draw, then 27/29 on the second and 26/28 on the third?

Comment: Yes, that is the way.

Comment: Yes, that's right : you are on the good track! Something which is misleading in this question is that the money amounts do not play any role. Maybe in a further question ?

Comment: Thank you! I think the amounts were there to show us that it matters that someone wins first or second or third, that the three prizes are not the same, but that is only a guess.

Comment: I think you are right in saying this.